# How to get input autofill value on click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML Code:

```
 <input type="text" class="organizationSearch" id="organizationSearch" name="NAME">
 <table>
 <tr class="organName" style="display:none;"><td width="124px"><b><span>Organization Name</span>:</b></td><td id="organName"></td></tr>

$("#organizationSearch").live('mouseout mouseleave keyup change click',function(){  
    var organSearch=$(this).val();  
    $('#organName').text(organSearch);  
});
```

Comment: is `#organName` an `<input>` element? Post your HTML structure as well please.

Comment: Why binding mouseout & mouseleave? mouseout should be enough. On modern browsers, using oninput event would be better (paste would be included too)

Answer (score 1):

First thing don't use live,it is deprecated and try like

```
$("#organizationSearch").on('focus',function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on instead of .live like this.

```
$(document).on('mouseout mouseleave keyup change click','#organizationSearch',function(){  
  var organSearch=$(this).val();  
  $('#organName').text(organSearch);  
});
```

Comment: Why are you tracking 5 different events on `document`? Don't do this.

Comment: Its based on question. please check question.